# font and font size of AlertDialog.Builder positive and negative buttons

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using the AlertDialog.Builder in a number of places in my app, but there are a few places where a more complex dialog is needed, and with more buttons. For the sake of consistency, I'd like the buttons in the complex dialogs to mirror the style of the standard positive/negative/neutral buttons. How can I discover which font is used by default in the standard dialog, as well as the associated font size?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information is available in the Material Design guidelines, though it is somewhat scattered.

Button text size info is listed on this page: https://material.io/guidelines/style/typography.html

> Buttons
>
> English: Medium 14sp, all caps

Comment: Thanks for the link. The font, I infer from the information on the linked page, is Roboto.